# Map of alphabet - how many times each letter occurs in a string (including 0)

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashtable

I am writing a function that returns an array of how many times each letter of the alphabet (a-z) occurs in a string, including 0. This array only contains 26 numbers. So far this is the function I've come up with. It works, but I feel like must be a cleaner way to refactor this solution.

```
export function generateMap(text){

 const text_arr = text.toLowerCase().split('');
 const valid_char = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('')

 const map = {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 0, 'h': 0, 'i': 0, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 0, 'n': 0, 'o': 0, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 0, 's': 0, 't': 0, 'u': 0, 'v': 0, 'w': 0, 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}


 text_arr.forEach(char => {
   if(valid_char.indexOf(char) > -1) map[char]++
 })

 return Object.values(map)

}
```

Comment: You might consider iterating through the string and then using the charcodeat function. This returns the unicode value for each letter.  For example 'A' is 65.  This number could be the position in the array that you augment the counter.  You might have to offset it and so 'a' gives you position zero in the array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using ES6, let's try extending `Map` with some additional functionality to make this straightforward. We'll add an `update()` function for semantically incrementing, and a `get()` function that returns a default value (for example, `0`), if the key does not exist on the map yet:

```js
class DefaultMap extends Map {
  constructor (defaultValue, iterable = []) {
    super(iterable)
    this.default = defaultValue
  }

  get (key) {
    if (this.has(key)) {
      return super.get(key)
    }

    return this.default
  }

  update (key, fn) {
    this.set(key, fn(this.get(key)))
  }
}

const initialCharCode = 'a'.charCodeAt(0)

// generate the valid characters from the ASCII table a-z
const validChars = Array.from(
  {length: 26},
  (value, index) => String.fromCharCode(index + initialCharCode)
)

function generateMap (text) {
  const chars = text.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, '').toLowerCase().split('')
  const map = new DefaultMap(0)

  chars.forEach(char => map.update(char, count => count + 1))

  return validChars.map(validChar => map.get(validChar))
}

console.log(generateMap('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'))
```

We then define the `validChars` a single time, statically, outside the function `generateMap()` since we only need to do that once. We also get our array by mapping `validChars` rather than calling `Object.values()` on the `map`, so that iteration order is guaranteed by specification rather than implementation.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

```
export function generateMap(text){

    var text_arr = text.toLowerCase().split('').sort();

    const valid_char = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('').sort();
    const map = {};

    valid_char.forEach(char => {
        var count = text_arr.lastIndexOf(char) + 1;
        text_arr = text_arr.slice(count);
        map[char] = count;
    });

    return Object.values(map)
}
```

`sort()` on `valid_char` is a warranty.

Comment: I've thought of this solution, but it doesn't account for the letters that do not occur in the text (should be 0 in the map).

Comment: `sort()` is a "warranty"? That doesn't make any sense. It's already sorted, and that will never be untrue, not to mention object properties are unordered, so it doesn't even matter in the first place.

Comment: yes @PatrickRoberts, warranty that `valid_char` is also order, no matter the order chars in `valid_char` string. and yes, it matter also in the first place: the two arrays **have to be** both ordered in the same way.

Comment: sure, i can see it. it is to point up the key aspect of function. make clearer these aspects is, in general, not less important than write correct code.